# ios 16 lockscreen playbutton is disabled but working fine with ios15 (iphone11)

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, lockscreen, avplayerviewcontroller, ios16

I have used avplayer and avplayerViewController to play a video from url.

I can control lockscreen play/pause button through avaudiosession as below--

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback  error:&sessionError];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

Its working fine with iphone having ios 15, can control play/pause from lockscreen.

But in ios 16 iphone , the play/pause button is disabled.

Can anyone please help me why its not working with ios 16.

Comment: The issue with AVPlayer was fixed in iOS 16.1. Can you mention the OS version

Comment: The os version is 16.3.1 (Iphone 11 pro)